# php - rand() update image with the name of the previous one

Tags: php, random, updates, crud

I have a table CRUD that display my database.
When I upload an image in my image folder I generate a random name of numbers with that function `rand()`

Here is what I have coded :

My upload function

```
function importer_image()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["image"]))
    {
        $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']);
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
        $destination = './upload/' . $new_name;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        return $new_name;
    }
}
```

My upload php

```
if($_POST["operation"] == "Ajouter")
    {
        $image = '';
        if($_FILES["image"]["name"] != '')
        {
            $image = importer_image();
        }
```

The problem is then when I code the update function, the substitued image stays in my folder and the new one has a new name generated. In order to avoid this, I would like to create a condition that says `if $image !=''` 1/ erase the old file 2/ upload the new file and keep the same name than the deleted image.

So I'm trying to create an **update** php process that would 1/ delete `unlink()` 2/ upload the new image **with the name of the previous image**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to delete the old image and maintain new name of image as previous, you have to take a hidden input in your form which contain your uploaded image name.

For e.g :

```
<input type="hidden" name="old-image" value="here is your previous image">
```

Now when your upload function will hit then you can get previous image name by request and can delete or maintain new image as previous.

```
if($_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
    $old_image = $_POST['old-image'];  // get old image
    $new_name = $old_image; // make new image name as previous
    unlink('/upload/'.$old_image); // remove old image from folder
    $destination = './upload/' . $new_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
    return $new_name;
} else {
    //if there is no image uploaded in the form then it will maintain old image
    return $new_name= $_POST['old-image']; 
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to get extension works only if you have just one dot in the uploaded filename, it won't work for example on `image_a.1.jpg`. Use instead:

```
$extension = strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'],'.');
```

Also, using `rand()` for naming will eventually give you a headache when it generates the same number the second time and the uploaded image will overwrite the old one or not get saved, possibly producing error showing the user your full server save path. I'd use some hashing, like:

```
$new_name = md5($_FILES['image']['name'] . time());
```

If you need to save the file name as int, use `crc32()` instead of `md5()`. You could convert `md5()` result to int, but that would produce a very long int (128bit) that might not fit in your database or even PHP code.